# OData $filter with items in a $expand

Tags: wcf, filter, filtering, odata, expand

I have given some web services to access informations.

The first thing that i have tries to expand a node . And i have done that successfully with following code

```
http://www.domain.com/ODataService/WorkService.svc/CaseStudies?format=json&$expand=ServiceOfferings
```

Now i want to filter ServiceOfferingID that i will get when expanding ServiceOfferings .
How can use filter option against a expanded collection

```
http://www.domain.com/ODataService/WorkService.svc/CaseStudies?format=json&$expand=ServiceOfferings&$filter=ServiceOfferings.ServiceOfferingID eq 127
```

But its not working. What is right way to do the same

Comment: Short answer: change the dot to a slash, i.e. `&$filter=ServiceOfferings/ServiceOfferingID eq 127` should work.

Answer (score 58):

The query you'll need to write depends on the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) of the expanded collection.

Here are some examples that use the public [sample OData Northwind service, provided by odata.org](http://www.odata.org/odata-services/#v3).

*An order is always done by exactly one customer.*

Find the orders made by a customer with a specific name:
[http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=Customer/CompanyName eq 'Vins et alcools Chevalier'](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=Customer/CompanyName%20eq%20%27Vins%20et%20alcools%20Chevalier%27). This is equivalent to the answer of Dhawal.

*A customer can issue many orders.*

Use the [quantifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification#Logic) **all** or **any** to specify whether you want at least one, or all of the orders to obey your conditions.

1. Find customers for which one or more orders have been processed by a specific employee:
   [http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/**any**(o: o/EmployeeID eq 9)](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/any%28o:%20o/EmployeeID%20eq%209%29)
2. Find customers that haven't ordered anything for a long time:
   [http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/**all**(o: o/OrderDate lt DateTime'1997-01-01')](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/all%28o:%20o/OrderDate%20lt%20DateTime%271997-01-01%27%29)

You can call http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata and inspect the NavigationProperty elements, to see which relations exist.

```
<NavigationProperty Name="Orders" 
    Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Orders_Customers" 
    ToRole="Orders" 
    FromRole="Customers"/>
```

Then, look for an association with that name and you'll find the cardinality:

```
<Association Name="FK_Orders_Customers">
    <End 
         Type="NorthwindModel.Customer" 
         Role="Customers" 
         Multiplicity="0..1"/>
    <End 
         Type="NorthwindModel.Order" 
         Role="Orders" 
         Multiplicity="*"/>
    ...
```

Navigating a one-to-many relationship like this: [http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/EmployeeID eq 9](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=Orders/EmployeeID%20eq%209), will give you: *"The parent value for a property access of a property 'EmployeeID' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."*

Navigating a many-to-one relationship with all or any, like [http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=Customer/any(c: c/CompanyName eq 'Vins et alcools Chevalier')](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$expand=Customer&$filter=Customer/any%28c:%20c/CompanyName%20eq%20%27Vins%20et%20alcools%20Chevalier%27%29), will give you:
"Any/All may only be used following a collection."

By the way, `all()` and `any()` are actually the [Universal quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), ∀() and the [existential quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification), ∃(), respectively, which you may remember from math class.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Simple.OData.Client`? I'm curious if a filtered expansion is supported by it.

Answer (score 14):

Filtering by child object's properties is supported in oData.

Here is an example:
[http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter=Customer/Country eq 'Germany'](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter=Customer/Country%20eq%20'Germany')

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is achievable with `Simple.OData.Client`?

Answer (score 7):

Might be helpful for someone

```
GET serviceRoot/People?$expand=Trips($filter=Name eq 'Trip in US')
```

Comment: @Muhammad_Tayyab Do you know how you would go about formatting the url to only return results where the expand dataset is not null?   For example Trips might equal "Trips": []

Comment: This indeed the format I expect, but the service I talk to (Microsoft Dataverse) ignores the filter and returns all items.

Comment: @Creative Did you figure this out? Im having the same issue where I use the filter but its ignored and returns everything.

Answer (score 6):

In OData the Filter command only works on the top level element. For your filter to work you would need to have the following URL

`http://www.example.com/ODataService/WorkService.svc/CaseStudies(x)/ServiceOfferings?format=json&$filter=ServiceOfferingID eq 127`

Obviously this isn't the query you are trying to write, but behind the scenes your query is being converted to an expression tree which has a root expression based on the top level element.

If you really required to filter the data you could potentially intercept the query and write your own expression as below:

```
[QueryInterceptor("CaseStudies")]
public Expression<Func<CaseStudie, bool>> CaseStudieFilter()
{
    <Expression here>
}
```

Comment: @nil if you read the question they are actually talking about filtering on an expand which is what my answeer addresses, this is different to filtering on a complex type, so although you may say this is not true it is for expands

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this through a webget on the service. I have had to do something similar to filter by properties of properties.