# Odata $expand and $filter together for list of object

Tags: vb.net, odata

This the response i have from the backend(vb.net)
and I have tried this way to filter specific values are name and id but not working

http://localhost:26209/odata/SeasonList?$expand=season($filter=season/name eq '2017')
http://localhost:26209/odata/SeasonList?$expand=season&$filter=season/name eq '2017'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171310/odata-filter-with-items-in-a-expand).

Or you could probably try these [examples](https://www.odata.org/odata-services/#v3)

```
http://localhost:26209/odata/SeasonList?$expand=season&$filter=season/name eq '2017 Tournaments'
```

Comment: Error occurs as **The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a property access of a property 'name' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value**

Answer (score 0):

You need a lambda operator to filter a list of values.

```
$filter=season/any(s:s/name eq '2017 Tournaments')
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-usage#lambda-operators
- https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/odata-query-options/#45-filtering-by-association