# Reacr-Admin, OData: how to filter a list by nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, odata, react-admin

I receive the following data:

```
[
  {
    userId:1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      email: gmail1,
      personId: 55,
      person: {
        id: 55,
        firstName: "Adams"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    userId:2,
    user: {
      id: 2,
      email: gmail2,
      personId: 43, 
      person: {
        id: 43,
        firstName: "john"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And the problem is that because of this design, I cannot filter the data by the **firstName** field.
Can you help make **filtering correctly means React-Admin**

Comment: I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12647843/3797799) is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just access properties

```
const filtered = data.filter((d) => d.user.person.firstName === term)
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      email: "gmail1",
      personId: 55,
      person: {
        id: 55,
        firstName: "Adams",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    user: {
      id: 2,
      email: "gmail2",
      personId: 43,
      person: {
        id: 43,
        firstName: "john",
      },
    },
  },
]

const term = "john"

const filtered = data.filter((d) => d.user.person.firstName === term)

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: It might be a good practice to check if `user` and `person` exist.