# Acumatica OpenAPI can not search stock item by barcode in cross references

Tags: join, filter, odata, acumatica

I'm trying to use OpenAPI to fetch data from Acumatica.The filter is barcode in CROSS-REFERENCEE[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtLmB.png).
It's unable to fetch data([before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwCPJ.png)) because

```
 "The parent value for a property access of a property 'AlternateID' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."
```

I did some research and find a same question([OData $filter with items in a $expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171310/odata-filter-with-items-in-a-expand)).
I changed([after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgtgX.png)) my request but still get

```
"exceptionMessage": "The method or operation is not implemented." error.
```

I really know nothing about `OData` and `C#`.I use `JAVA/NODEJS` to fetch data. Can someone give me any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works for me: ``https://localhost/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem?$expand=CrossReferences&filter=AlternateType%20eq%20'BAR'%20and%20AlternateID%20eq%20'1234567890'``

Comment: Deetz, If you add a $ to your filter command it errors out.  Without it it just ignores it.

Comment: @PatrickChen - I see that. I went down the same path as OP and it seems perhaps Acumatica doesn't support that sort of filtering. It's not in the docs at least.

Comment: May be the only way is create a GI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way.

Acumatica [doesn't support filtration](https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c5e2f36a-0971-4b33-b127-3c3fe14106ff) over the detail records.
Instead, you can create a new GI that will contain the information from the Inventory Item and corresponding Alternate IDs and request the records from that GI.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Samvel Petrosov .